# Como retornar apenas un campo que varios que cumplan la condición en un select

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sybase

El cliente tiene 3 campos de teléfono: telefono1, telefono2, telefono3 , de estos: a) los 3  pueden estar bien ingresados, b) 2  pueden estar bien ingresados , c) 1  puede estar bien ingresado o d) ni uno está bien ingresado. El select que construí ya me responde la situación d. El problema ocurre cuando se cumplen las situaciones a, b o c pués solo quiero obtener 1 campo correcto que será usado para corrección en otra tabla.

```
SELECT IDE,telefono1,telefono2,telefono3
FROM tabla_cliente
WHERE IDE = 12345
and ( 1 = case when ( length(telefono1) = 9 and telefono1 <> 999999999 ) then 1 else 0 end
or 1 = case when ( length(telefono2) = 9 and telefono2 <> 999999999 ) then 1 else 0 end
or 1 = case when ( length(telefono3) = 9 and telefono3 <> 999999999 ) then 1 else 0 end )
and rownum <= 1
```

Cómo hago para el select retorne algo como esto IDE,telefono_correcto

En telefono_correcto contendría el 1ro de los 3 campos que cumpla la condición: tiene 9 dígitos y es diferente a 99999999.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes por ejemplo hacer un case que determine el campo a usar en función de las condiciones que necesitas. Ese mismo campo generado puedes utilizarlo para evaluar si el registro tiene un teléfono válido:

```sql
SELECT
    IDE,
    CASE
        WHEN LENGTH(telefono1) == 9 AND telefono1 != 999999999 THEN telefono1
        WHEN LENGTH(telefono2) == 9 AND telefono2 != 999999999 THEN telefono2
        WHEN LENGTH(telefono3) == 9 AND telefono3 != 999999999 THEN telefono3
        ELSE 999999999
    END as telefono_correcto
from test
WHERE telefono_correcto != 999999999
```